# Can't find a previusly saved .obj

Tags: modeling, import, file-format, blend-files

I can't find my model. I don't know if it's Blender or where I'm saving it or if it's just what I'm trying to save.

I've been wanting to make some tweaks on a ROBLOX model for a while now, But the thing is whenever I save it as an OBJ. I can never find it in Blender, yet when I open my files (**not** in Blender)  It's there.

***I'm new to Blender*** so it's probably obvious what I'm doing wrong anyways lol

[image]

Comment: Blender's native format is not .obj. Such file format has to be **imported**. The open function in blender is for .blend files

Answer (score 2):

You want to import .obj and you opening .blend
Go to *file* -> *import* -> *Wavefront (obj)*

Answer (score 0):

Another approach - If you go back into Blender and load the model's blender file, click on File-->Export--Obj and see what folder (and drive) it's going to save it to.  That's probably where your missing obj file is.

If it's not there get Windows to do a full search for that filename.